# Mandrill API mis-reports bad formats

Tags: google-analytics, mailchimp

As specified in the documentation, I have to send arrays for google_analytics_domains and google_analytics_campaign fields.

http://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.html#method=send

But mandrill generates a link with a wrong utm_campaign (Google analytics doesn't like the [0] part) :

```
utm_campaign[0]=test_campaign
```

I tried to send strings instead of arrays but the mandrallapi kicks me out (Please enter an array)... Did i miss something ? Thanks for your help !

Here is a request example with mandrillapp:

```
{
   "key":"apikey",
   "message":{
      "html":"example html",
      "text":"example text",
      "subject":"example subject",
      "from_email":"from_email@example.com",
      "from_name":"example from_name",
      "to":[
         {
            "email":"email@example.com",
            "name":"example name"
         }
      ],
      "headers":{
         "...":"..."
      },
      "track_opens":true,
      "track_clicks":true,
      "auto_text":true,
      "url_strip_qs":true,
      "bcc_address":"bcc_address@example.com",
      "merge":true,
      "global_merge_vars":[
         {
            "name":"example name",
            "content":"example content"
         }
      ],
      "merge_vars":[
         {
            "rcpt":"rcpt@example.com",
            "vars":[
               {
                  "name":"example name",
                  "content":"example content"
               }
            ]
         }
      ],
      "tags":[
         "example tags[]"
      ],
      "google_analytics_domains":[
         "..."
      ],
      "google_analytics_campaign":[
         "..."
      ],
      "metadata":[
         "..."
      ],
      "attachments":[
         {
            "type":"example type",
            "name":"example name",
            "content":"example content"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm having this same problem, too, albeit through the mandrill gem for rails.  In my case, the gem formats the APi call, so I never see a 'right' way to make this call.

Comment: Have your tried emailing Mandrill support? I've found them to be very responsive and helpful. http://help.mandrill.com/customer/portal/emails/new